Warm water outdoor Dog wash
Can you run the hot water from the washing machine faucet through a regular garden hose ? And then use a y connector to control the temperature through the flow control valves ?

There are adapters to connect almost anything to almost anything.  You need to be careful with hot water since it can burn skin in seconds.  One reason that anti-scald valves, or keeping the hot water at/below 120F is recommended/required these days.

hot water in garden hoses is an interesting problem. sometimes it's good, sometimes not.  appliance hose would work, but is much more expensive.
It would probably be best to install a shower mixer outdoors

It sucks having to wait to remove all the hot water from a garden hose to get cold water to drink on a hot day.

Most garden hoses are not certified for drinking water.

neither are my hands, but I'll drink from them.  what comes out of a hose mostly depends on what goes in the other end.  If your water supply is potable it's most probably not a problem,  but not if it's a dodgy well.

They sell Y-mixers specifically made for the washer hookups. For example:
https://www.lowes.com/pd/EASTMAN-12-in-L-3-4-in-Hose-Thread-Inlet-x-3-4-in-Outlet-Rubber-Washing-Machine-Connector/3546270
The end of the Y connects directly to a garden hose.
Make sure to open both hot and cold water faucets at the same time, then control the temperature by partially closing the hot or cold.
